# Auto fill OTP in IOS using react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, autofill

I have added a autofill OTP feature to my application coded in react native and for that I have utilised the react-native-otp-verify library (Works on android).

Particularly for IOS, I am not able to make it work as it requires us to send the sms in a specific format (in order to read the OTP), or rather adhere to set of rules / guidelines.

Is there any other workaround / solution in order to resolve this issue?

Till now I have included adding in the textContentType property and setting it to "oneTimeCode" to the TextInput component. This solution is mentioned in the react native documentation.

But I can't change the format of the sms message received on my phone, hence I am not able to implement the autofill functionality in IOS.